# What does a bar symbol in parallel with a single inductor indicate?

Tags: inductor

Some circuits have parallel bars on their inductor symbols such as:

[image]

Does that mean the inductor is wound around a magnetic core instead of air? Is that how a differential choke is represented?

Answer (score 5):

Typically yes. The bar is used to indicate some form of ferrous core.

[image]

https://www.conceptdraw.com/How-To-Guide/inductors-symbols

Answer (score 4):

A solid bar indicates a [ferrous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferrous) core (core made of a ferrous metal, such as iron).

A dashed bar indicates a [ferrite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferrite_(magnet)) core.

Comment: ferrous core never heard of it. did you mean fameous?

Comment: @cm64 What Electron means is a core made of a ferrous metal, such as iron or steel.

Comment: yes.. iron or steel based core

Comment: Are both cores insrted in the inductor to increase its inductance?

Comment: Any difference of their use in applications?

Comment: yes.. air core colis will have much more less inductance when compared to iron or ferrite core inductors.

Comment: air core inductors mostly going to use in RF circuits.. in order to reduce core losses (hysteresis and eddy current).

Comment: "Ferrous", made of *ferrum*, chemical symbol Fe, latin for iron.

Comment: @Transistor Nice information, do you know the difference between the use of ferrite and ferrous cores? Is one of them of the same amount increases the inductance of the inductor more?  Which one is used when?

Comment: Ferrite is powered ferrous material.

Answer (score 2):

I see this convention for ferrites such as in the filter you show, tho I can't seem to find an official source indicating this is an official standard of some kind.

Answer (score 1):

Well, IEEE Std 315 specifies this symbol for an inductor with a "magnetic core":

[image: inductor with core, symbol from IEEE Std 315]

The standard doesn't show any symbols with a single bar, at least as far as I can see.

Comment: When I was a boy, British laminated FeSi cores had three lines; ferrite cores were a single dashed or sometimes dotted line.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yes, I have also seen many variations over the years. I just wanted to point out that there really is a standard way of drawing these things.